# Suggestions please for finishing multi select list date in MVC Razor and Knockout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've cobbled together a date picker in MVC 4 with Knockout 2.0 and am interested in getting suggestions on how to improve it and ultimately make it re-useable across the application.

My client prefers this format consisting of select lists for each datepart.

The code does not set initial/final state yet. I does control workflow by enabling/disabling lists and looks up the days in the month selected.

Thanks for your suggestions.

http://jsfiddle.net/mathewvance/jz5QN/

```
@{
    var yearOptions = Enumerable.Range(1930, 2010-1930+1);
    var monthOptions = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
        .MonthNames
        .TakeWhile(x => x != String.Empty)
        .Select((x,i) => new  
        {  
          Value = i,  
          Text = x
        });
}


<div id="the_model">
    <form>
        <div class="editor-row">
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { data_bind = "value: birthDate" })
            <select data-bind="options: yearOptions, value: birthDateYear, optionsCaption: 'year'"></select>&nbsp;
            <select data-bind="enable: birthDateYear, options: monthOptions, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', value: birthDateMonth, optionsCaption: 'month'"></select>&nbsp;
            <select data-bind="enable: birthDateMonth, options: dayOptions, value: birthDateDay, optionsCaption: 'day'"></select>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function daysInMonth(month, year) {
        return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }

    var yearOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(yearOptions));
    var monthOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(monthOptions));

    var TheModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        this.birthDate = ko.observable('@Model.BirthDate');
        this.birthDateYear = ko.observable();
        this.birthDateMonth = ko.observable();
        this.birthDateDay = ko.observable();

        this.dayOptions = ko.observableArray([]);

        this.submit = function () {
            // validate and post
        };

            this.birthDateYear.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log('birthDateYear: ' + val);
    if(parseInt(val) > 0) {
        self.fillDayOptions();
    }
});

this.birthDateMonth.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log('birthDateMonth: ' + val);
    if(parseInt(val) > 0) {
        self.fillDayOptions();
    }
});

this.birthDateDay.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log('birthDateDay: ' + val);
    if(parseInt(val) > 0){
        self.birthDate(getBirthDate(self.birthDateYear(), self.birthDateMonth(), val));
    }
});

this.fillDayOptions = function() {
    //self.birthDateDay({});

    var month = self.birthDateMonth();
    var year = self.birthDateYear();

    if(month && year) {
        self.dayOptions([]);
        for(var  i = 0; i < daysInMonth(month, year); i++) {
            self.dayOptions.push(i + 1);
        }
    }

    //self.birthDateDay(null);
};

    var viewModel = new TheModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("the_model"));
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Hi Judah,

Having a specific issue now where I am unable to reset the days select list. If a date is chosen and the users goes back and changes the year and/or month, the day select list should be set back to the caption when birthDateDay(null).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mathewvance/jz5QN/

Comment: Interesting. I'm unable to find the problem. It may be related to removing all the day options and starting again with new items. It may be a bug in the options binding.

Comment: Ok, more investigation found the problem. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optionsCaption binding parameter actually *adds* a option to the list of options at the beginning of the list.

Therefore, when you write code that clears out all the options and replaces them with new options, the optionsCaption special item doesn't really exist as far as Knockout is concerned. That's your problem.

To solve this, simply change your removal code to skip the first item: [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jz5QN/11/)

Comment: Looks good and thanks for that. I can set a value and validate based on changes to just the day observable now.

Comment: Cool. If that solves your problem, I'd much appreciate marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: ah... I tried marking answered by voting it up before. You have to click the check mark, got it! thanks again